# How to set some cells as fixed width and some cells variable width of a single table in html css?

Tags: html, css

In my html I've used

```
table{
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

its fixing the entire table cells. but I need some cells are fixed and some need to be variable?
How to do that? I'm a beginner please do help

Answer (score 0):

If you set the table layout to fixed, you should still be able to explicitly set the width on specific `<td>` and `<th>` cells.

Here's an example [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elliotstarks/p6j7wvxu/)